# Rejection and Saying-no tags

Tags: discussion, tags

## Rejection and Saying-no tags

Do we really need both? Should they be synonyms?

Answer (score 7):

I notice that all four questions using the [saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no) tag are about how the asker can say no to someone. Out of the two questions using the [rejection](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rejection) tag, [one](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/116/102) deals with something different: Interacting with someone after they reject the asker in some way, or say no to them.

The two are certainly very different sides of the same coin, so to speak, and so the question boils down to whether we're comfortable with having both be in the same tag, or whether they're different enough to justify different tags (although I'd want to see perhaps better names, if possible).

My two cents is that it could go either way at the moment. We don't have enough data. Let's revisit it in a while, once we see patterns emerge. If only one case (e.g. dealing with rejection) becomes popular, then perhaps the other doesn't need its own tag (or a tag at all). But with only five questions using at least one of the tags, I think it's too early to choose.

My point, though, is that they represent two different types of situations - not necessarily parts of the same one.

Comment: `rejection` might be used by someone who is experiencing constant rejection by his/her peers. Just a possibility.

Comment: @Vylix Yeah, that's also true. It would still fit into the category of "being on the receiving end of rejection".